# segmentation fault while generating a number of random numbers using rand() in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program where I need to set a number of elements (specified by the blanks variable) of a 2D array (board) to be 0.(array size is 9x9) These locations has to be picked up in random and once I use the following code segment to do it, the program ends up in a segmentation fault in some instances and does not set the required number of positions to 0.

```
i = rand() % 10;
j = rand() % 10;

if (board[i][j]){
    board[i][j] = 0;
    blanks--;
}
```

I have been looking up on this issue bit and came to know that `rand()` is not thread safe. Is it the reason for the segmentation fault I am getting, or is it something else?

Further, is there a workaround for this? (For me to get a set of random numbers without this segmentation fault)

Comment: Most likely `board` has not been correctly allocated - it would need to have 10 rows x 10 columns.

Comment: Got it. So the not thread-safe thing has nothing to do with rand() ?

Comment: Indeed - that was irrelevant. For future reference if you'd run this under your debugger you would have seen the error straight away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your requirement

> *(array size is 9x9)*

your array index should run **upto** `8`. `C` arrays have `0` based index.

Change

```
i = rand() % 10;
j = rand() % 10;
```

to

```
i = rand() % 9;
j = rand() % 9;
```